# Length of life of a fire detector

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The length of life of a flame detector is exponentially distributed with paramater $\lambda=0.1/year$. Die number of events which activate the flame detector in an interval with length $t$ (heat, smoke etc.) is poisson distributed with paramter $\mu t,\mu=0.1/year$

Question: What is the probability, that the flame detector never makes an alarm during his whole length of life.

My attempt: $L$ is the length of life until the first alarm and $X$ is the time until the first alarm. Now I would like to calculate the common density function of $L$ and $X$

The density function of the exponentially distributed event is $F(x)=1-e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x\ge 0$ for the possion distribution we get the relgularised gamma function $Q(n+1,\lambda)$ but I do not see how to reach the goal, may you help me with this probability exercise.

Comment: Where did you get your Gamma function from?  You can work out the probability $X>t$ for fixed $t$ and you should have that $X$ and $L$ are iid. (Since $\lambda = \mu$)

Comment: Could you show me how to do that, I thought it can be done using the common density function, i.e $P(X>t)=1-F(x)$ where $F(x)$ represents the density function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got off to a good start, the random variable $X$ is what you should be looking at.

First, what's the probability that $X>t$?  Well the statement $X>t$ means that there were no incidents in the interval $[0,t]$. As the number of incedents in this interval is a Poisson mean $\mu t$ we may calculate
$$P[X>t] = e^{-\mu t} \frac{(\mu t)^0}{0!} = e^{-\mu t}$$

For the exponential random variable $L$ we have that $P[L>t] = e^{-\lambda t}$.

Now as $\mu = \lambda$ the distributions of the two random variables are equal. We may assume from the context of the question that they are independent.

So if $X$ and $L$ are independent and identically distributed the probability that $P[X>L] = P[L>X]$ by symmetry. As $P[X=L] = 0$ for continuous random variables we must have 
 $$P[X>L] = P[L>X] = 0.5$$

Comment: Thank you, so if I understand it correctly, 0.5 is the probability that there is no incident during the whole life of the fire detector, correct?

Comment: Correct, but the "trick" works because $\lambda = \mu$ if this is not true you have to do a little more work to show that the probability of no incidents is $\frac\mu{\lambda+\mu}$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I posted also another probability question, may you can help with that also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388414/arbitrary-point-b-on-circle